# Apple keyboard swap

Tags: keyboard, apple

Hey:) I'm having a problem with an apple keyboard on my linux machine.

The less then / greater than key is swapped with my "°" key.
The less than / greater than key is usually on the right side of shift as it shows on the keyboard.

Do you guys know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

(There must be perfect keyboard configuration files for your model/layout).

Anyway, **The old way**:

1 - find those keys:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep -Pw "degree|less" > mychanges
```

2 - edit "mychanges" to swap the keys. You probably have something like:

```
keycode 94 = less greater less greater bar brokenbar bar
keycode 49 = dead_circumflex degree dead_circumflex degree U2032 U2033 U2032
```

Swap the keys codes to:

```
keycode 49 = less greater less greater bar brokenbar bar
keycode 94 = dead_circumflex degree dead_circumflex degree U2032 U2033 U2032
```

3 - activate the changes with

```
xmodmap mychanges
```

4 - if your are happy with the new behaviour, do

```
cat mychanges >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

This approach can be used to generic keyboard changes (in graphic mode)

Comment: Thank you guys, i solved it the old way. Yeah for some reason when i choose apple in layouts of settings/keyboard it still shows up like it did. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4):

### Select Apple Keyboard

I know this sounds silly, but there is actually an option in your **Settings** -> **Keyboard** that will get rid of this issue.  You'll want to select an Apple/Mac keyboard.

### Manually 'Select' Apple Keyboard at Boot

I used to use this method, until I realized the above method worked for me.

- ## `echo "0" > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout`

This will replace the content of the `iso_layout` file with the value `0`