# "º" and "<" swapped on spanish Apple Aluminum keyboard - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, swap, xkb

I have a spanish (european) Apple Aluminum keyboard hooked to my ubuntu'd Mac Mini, it works fine but the keys for < and º/ª are swapped, and they remain swapped, even though my keyboard seems to be configured correctly. How do I swap 'em (or unswap them, I guess)?

btw this is º/ª (think spanish equivalent of -nd, -rd) not degree as far as I know (usually comes with a line under it but some fonts render both symbols exactly the same.)

Thank you so much in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling: I have pieced together a solution.

First step: use `xev` to capture both keys, takes out the guesswork. For me they were 49 & 94.

once you have the key codes, do this:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep -Pw "49|94" > mychanges
```

Or whatever your keycodes are instead of 49 & 94, though, they're probably the same if you have the problem with º & < on a spanish keyboard.

Then, edit "mychanges" to swap the keys. You probably have something like:

```
keycode  49 = masculine ordfeminine grave asciitilde backslash backslash
keycode  94 = less greater less greater bar brokenbar bar brokenbar
```

Swap the numbers for those two, then `xmodmap mychanges`, try it out, if you like it do `cat mychanges >> ~/.Xmodmap`

Sources:

[Getting character key code mappings in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245333/getting-character-key-code-mappings-in-ubuntu)

[Apple keyboard swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572648/apple-keyboard-swap)

Comment: Brilliant, you made may day. I had exactly the same problem with my italian macbook keyboard under linux.
Thanks!

Comment: You're awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I cannot give one hundred +1s but this was great. I was struggling with pandoc and LaTeX ':(