# Key remapping reversal coupled to built-in device disconnection

Tags: remapping

I have 3 keyboard languages in my Ubuntu 20.

A key <kbd>< ></kbd> needs to be corrected by:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = less greater"
```

As far as I remember having Ubuntu 19 need not further steps.

It is related to an invalid [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/40148), in which the key in tty (outside X) behaves normally.

However, currently the key reverses to its incorrect <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> state after a couple of minutes.

Answer should focus on keeping change after startup - avoid reversal. Please test in a canonical ubuntu 20 system before replying. Wait 5 to 10 minutes to check for reversal.

[image]

#### EDIT: Related to device disconnection (laptop built-in webcam)

I suspect this can be related to the repeated frequent disconnection of a device. Example: (my dmesg is full of this)

```
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:39 2021] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 23
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:39 2021] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] usb 1-5: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 4 endpoint 0x81 has invalid wMaxPacketSize 0
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b483, bcdDevice=99.14
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] usb 1-5: Product: USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam (04f2:b483)
[Mon Mar  1 12:01:40 2021] input: USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input43
```

I think when this event occurs from time to time, the keyboard reverses to its original wrong state. The reversal occurs in the laptop keyboard also.

However, the reversal is secondary to the failure to map correctly the key, in the beginning.

Comment: Is it related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/40148) perhaps?

Comment: What is the output of `cat ~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: @Ferroao Is your problem similar to this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/572648/apple-keyboard-swap

Comment: Related: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312847/fn-key-lock-of-logitech-keyboard/1313977#1313977) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts/1200910#1200910) read *how to preserve the change*

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Disable webcam as in: (my webcam is not faulty)

https://superuser.com/questions/982265/how-to-disable-a-specific-faulty-laptop-webcam-in-ubuntu

Load change at startup: (already had this in ubuntu 19)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SwapKeySpa
Exec=xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = less greater"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

save file as `.config/autostart/keyswap.desktop`